# TFS 2010 change history on individual code sections

Tags: version-control, tfs, code-analysis

Some time ago I recall seeing an early release video demonstration of a tool that allowed one to (from within Visual Studio) inspect the history of a section of code.
For example, right click on a method and choose 'view history', and see when that method has changed.
Can anyone recall what product this may have been?

Answer (score 5):

I don't recall that, but is Annotate something that helps you too. Annotate shows a copy of the source file and for each section who last modified it and when that happened.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx

Comment: Annotate becomes useless once methods start to move in the file.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is "method history" and we've just released it for [Subversion](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/method-history-for-subversion-is-here.html) and of course for [Plastic SCM](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/12/announcing-method-history.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant SemanticMerge: http://www.semanticmerge.com/